# Trying to install nuget getting "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install Autofac.MVC5 in my project (already have Autofac nuget installed on the same project) and I'm getting `An item with the same key has already been added.` error.

This is the output:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' with respect to project 'Core\MyProj.Core.Factory', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4'
Resolved actions to install package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4'
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
Adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added reference 'System.Web.Razor' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.1.0' to MyProj.Core.Factory
For adding package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
For adding package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' already exists in folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added reference 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' to MyProj.Core.Factory
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
Adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added reference 'System.Web.Helpers' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added reference 'System.Web.WebPages' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.1.0' to MyProj.Core.Factory
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
Adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added reference 'System.Web.Mvc' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.1.0' to MyProj.Core.Factory
For adding package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
For adding package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory' that targets 'net46'.
Adding package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' to folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Added reference 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Added package 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Autofac.Mvc5 3.3.4' to MyProj.Core.Factory
Added file 'app.config'.
Added file 'app.config'.
Added file 'app.config' to project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Removed package 'Autofac.Mvc5 3.3.4' from 'packages.config'
Removed reference 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Removed reference 'System.Web.Mvc.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Removed reference 'System.Web.Helpers.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed reference 'System.Web.WebPages.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' from 'packages.config'
Removed reference 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Removed reference 'System.Web.Razor.dll' from project 'MyProj.Core.Factory'
Removing package 'Autofac.Mvc5 3.3.4' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4\lib\net45'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4\lib'.
Removed file 'Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4.nupkg' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4'.
Removed package 'Autofac.Mvc5 3.3.4' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removing package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.1.0' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0\lib\net45'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0\Content'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0\lib'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0.nupkg' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.1.0'.
Removed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.1.0' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removing package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.1.0' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0\lib\net45'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0\Content'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0\lib'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0.nupkg' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.1.0'.
Removed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.1.0' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removing package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.1.0' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0\lib\net45'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0\lib'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0.nupkg' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0'.
Removed folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.1.0'.
Removed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.1.0' from folder 'F:\Development\MyProj\Server\packages'
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectResolver.GetBindingRedirects(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectResolver.GetBindingRedirects(IEnumerable`1 assemblyPaths, AppDomain domain)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.<<AddBindingRedirects>b__59_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.AddBindingRedirects()
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.MSBuildNuGetProject.PostProcessAsync(INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
========== Finished ==========
```

I thought it has to do with my app.config - so I tried saving it again - but it didn't work.

If I open a new console application and install that nuget then everything works. just on my project it doesn't.